# Why does Joi randomly play music?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner-2049

In *Blade Runner 2049*, at seemingly random points, Joi/the emanator plays a tune*. For example, it happens during K's visit to the Wallace headquarters, which leads Luv to ask K whether he is satisfied with the product. The scene can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/jMk99drt1B4?t=275). Why does the AI play a sound at those particular times?

<sub>* It's the Peter and the Wolf theme. There is quite a bit of discussion concerning the choice of music, see for example [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81169/what-is-the-significance-of-peter-and-the-wolf-in-blade-runner-2049) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/7zrzdv/theory_the_significance_of_the_peter_and_the_wolf/), but I am just asking why a jingle is played at those particular times. The answer might be "because the makers wanted to show off the Peter and the Wolf theme" but I hope it's not.</sub>

Comment: "The scene can be seen here" Presumably you copied this verbatim from your now deleted question & forgot to provide the actual link.

Comment: I don't have an answer that is considered canon, but, unless you set it otherwise, doesn't your smartphone constantly make sounds and noises for all kinds of notifications?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Well, if I went to such a meeting, especially one that seems very important to K, I'd set my smartphone to silent and given what we see what Joi can do, I'd expect her to be able to avoid interrupting the conversation automatically.

Comment: He's a police officer visiting a business that he has undoubtably visited a number of times before (given his line of business).  Yes, it means something more to him than usual, but there's nothing to expect him to be on 'best behavior' with them.

Comment: I would expect as a police officer to always be available to my superiors - which means leaving communications devices enabled.  Since Joi also seems to function for communication it would be left active.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, but I'm not sure why the musical theme itself is considered irrelavant in answering the question? From both an in-universe and out-of-universe standpoint, I would think the sound it makes would also be pretty important in understanding the use of choice at all...

Comment: I agree @DarthLocke ... the choice of Peter and the Wolf is both relevant in-universe and also why it was chosen by the Director.  That addition would make it more interesting than simply why K left the notification sound on.

Comment: @DarthLocke There is quite a bit of discussion concerning the choice of music, see for example [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81169/what-is-the-significance-of-peter-and-the-wolf-in-blade-runner-2049) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/7zrzdv/theory_the_significance_of_the_peter_and_the_wolf/). I'm rather asking about the relevance to the plot.

Comment: @iandotkelly I have added some links to the question that you might find interesting.

Comment: @AndreKR - I would think I would too, and others would, as well, but how many meetings have you been on where phones go off? How many TV or radio interviews have you heard where there are computer or phone alerts going off? And, particularly, why would K care, one way or the other, if this was secret or whether it was known that he had a hot holographic girlfriend?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet It's starting to feel like that is the answer, but it doesn't really fit with how I perceived the movie. K doesn't seem to have any colleagues that would randomly send him SMS and he doesn't seem the kind of guy who joins Facebook groups.